# What is the difference between usri2_comment and usri2_usr_comment?

Tags: winapi

In the Windows [`USER_INFO_2` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_info_2) there are two fields: `usri2_comment` and `usri2_usr_comment`. (Similarly, [`USER_INFO_3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_info_3) has `usri3_comment` and `usri3_usr_comment`, and [`USER_INFO_4`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_info_4) has `usri4_comment` and `usri4_usr_comment`.) The documentation explains that `usri2_comment` "contains a comment to associate with the user account" whereas `usri2_usr_comment` is "a Unicode string that contains a user comment". But it never makes clear what is the difference between the two – why are there two comment fields here? What is each supposed to be used for?

The `NET USER` command displays both in its output – it calls `usri2_comment` the "Comment", whereas `usri2_usr_comment` it calls the "User's comment". The former can be changed using the `/COMMENT` option whereas the later can be changed using the `/USERCOMMENT` option. But that still is unenlightening as to what the actual difference between them is.

Comment: Just an educated guess, really, but the former (`usri2_comment`) appears to be *about* the user (e.g. "Account set up for Associate Staff Member") whereas the latter (`usri2_usr_comment`) would seem to be addable *by* the user (e.g. "My name is Jim and I am an associate staff member").

Comment: @AdrianMole. Thanks. Interestingly I found some [old OS/2 doc](https://ia801208.us.archive.org/28/items/IBMOS2Warp4ToolkitDocuments2/srvfpqr.pdf) which says regarding `NetUserSetInfo` that (see page 466): "Administrator authority is required for all parmnum values, except when the following fields are set for a user's own account: usriX_usr_comment (parmnum = 7)..." However, despite that statement, in my testing a non-admin user gets "Access Denied" when running `NET USER username /USERCOMMENT:newcomment` on themselves. Haven't tried calling `NetUserSetInfo` directly yet though.

Comment: @AdrianMole Okay yes that's it. A non-admin can modify their usr_comment using NetUserSetInfo with an info level of 1012. Whereas a non-admin trying to change their comment (using info level 1007) fails. I assume `NET USER` is not using info level 1012 for `/USERCOMMENT:`, probably 2 or 3 or 4 instead, which would explain the Access Denied. (As an aside, the OS/2 NetUserSetInfo API has a different prototype from the Windows one, although both show their common Microsoft/IBM LAN Manager heritage.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is:

- `usri2_comment` is a comment set by the administrator. A non-administrator user cannot modify it even on their own account.
- `usri2_usr_comment` is a comment set by the user themselves. A non-administrator can modify it on their own account only.

A user can set their own `usri2_usr_comment` by calling `NetUserSetInfo` on themselves using info level 1012 (create a `USER_INFO_1012` structure and set the `usri1012_usr_comment` field to the new user comment).

Note however that, in my own testing, `NET USER username /USERCOMMENT:comment`, when run by a non-admin user on themselves, fails with an access denied error. I believe the reason for this is that the `NET USER` command is calling `NetUserSetInfo` with info level 2 (or 3 or 4) instead of 1012.